# vs2015 debug selected tests has never worked, no suppend on breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

c#

```
namespace MyTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTesterClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [HostType("ASP.NET")]
        [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("$(SolutionDir)\\MyWebProject", "/MyWebProject")]
        [UrlToTest("http://localhost:29633/")]  // FIXUP for your port
        public void MyTestMethod()
        {    
            Console.Out.WriteLine("BEFORE");
            Assert.IsTrue(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached);  // always fails
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("AFTER");
        }
}
```

`

IDE: VS2015 update 1 (on Win10), no extra 3rd party addons installed

Target: .net 4.5

Using IISExpress to test as a non-Administrator user (which is 32bit even on 64bit system for me)

Have 2 binds setup in IISExpress the "localhost:29633" and one to IP "192.168.0.2:29633" to allow across network testing and usage.  This is all working just fine.  This is setup in .vs\config\applicationhost.config with 2 entires bindingInformation=":29633:*" and bindingInformation=":29633:192.168.0.2"

**I can get my unit tests to pass successfully, but I can not get execution to stop at any breakpoint that is setup, either in code Break() or the IDE breakpoint window.**

So I provide a target test class to get working in your IDE to prove it should work for someone else as-is.
You'll need to create a dummy/empty ASP.NET project called "MyWebProject" and have this test case in its own project.

Things I have tried:

- Resetting all settings
- Ensuring both projects (MyTestProject and MyWebProject are rebuild and setup for Debug build types)
- Ensuring the ASP.NET debugging is enabled on that project.
- Modifying Test menu -> Test Settings -> Default Process Architecture from 32bit to 64bit.
- Modifying Test menu -> Test Settings -> Keep Test Execution Running
- Settings for debug symbols, disabling Just My Code,
- Settings for Common Properties -> Startup Project -> Multiple startup projects
- Tried this (but all my code in project is rebuilt, I do not need to debug any DLLs): Use Managed Compatibility Mode
- Lots of other things tried that I have simply forgotten now.  Have "Reset all settings" since.

If I try to attach to process (existing IISExpress.exe that runs in background between tests), then I can not start my tests at all, option "Run/Debug All Tests" greyed out.
If I try to start any other app, like running ASP.NET webapp on its own, again I can not start the tests the options are greyed out.
So it has to work from "Test [menu] -> Debug -> All Tests" and letting VS2015 start up all processes as needed, with debugger attached (ideally to both IISExpress.exe and TE.processhost.managed.exe).

What I find painful is that if something went wrong during the setup why didn't the unit test fail on the basis that VS2015 could not attach to process and then confirm correct setup of process so it was executing the expected copy of the project, etc..  Surly it should ALWAYS suspend execution at the start to allow VS to setup and communicate to inferior process being debugger, then execution resumed.  It should just fail unit test run and not even start the testing if the environment if not all setup as expected.

I notice what looks like 2 te.processhost.managed.exe (one is persistent across tests and one spawns during the current test run).  The breakpoint dialog indicates this process is the location of the test case breakpoints (but not ASP.NET ones)

But of course the ASP.NET runs in iisexpress.exe which is another process.

So is debugger attaching to both ok?  How can I see this while it should be the case?  How can I stop debugger cleaning up on termination, as this resets UI to many options in Debug -> Window -> ... are not available (if you are not quick enough).

If I set an ASP.NET breakpoint in code for example in Application_BeginRequest() from Global.asax/aspx execution does not stop in here either.

I am after a working project ZIP file and settings of the simplest test case project that proves the debugger is attached from VS so I can run-step though the code.

Comment: If you haven't tried already, you could try in VS2013 community edition, or even VS2017 community (you can have multiple side by side installs of VS2017, even the same edition,  so you can try many configurations of VS2017 easily) and/or try on a VM (free trial VMs available from Microsoft, Digital Ocean (I think) and probably others too).